# Laravel Livewire model property binding

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

This is my Livewire component

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Dashboard;

use App\Models\Post;
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class EditPost extends Component
{
    use AuthorizesRequests;

    public ?Post $postSingle = null;

    protected $rules = [
        'postSingle.priority' => 'digits_between:1,5',
    ];

    public function setPriority(Post $postSingle, $priority)
    {
        $this->authorize('update', $postSingle);
        $this->postSingle->priority = $priority;
    }

}
```

In my blade view I have
`<button wire:click="setPriority({{ $postSingle->id }}, 4)"></button>`

and somewhere else I show the priority with `{{ $postSingle->priority }}`

The reason why I don't do model property binding directly with `wire:model="postSingle.priority"` is that I want to run `$this->authorize('update', $postSingle);`.

What happens with the code below is that if I click the button, `$postSingle->priority` in the blade view is updated, but the Post record is not updated in my database. What am I missing?

Comment: Just use the save() method after assign value to the property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have overlooked actually saving the record.

```php
public function setPriority(Post $postSingle, $priority)
{
    $this->authorize('update', $postSingle);
    $this->postSingle->priority = $priority;

    // save the record
    $this->postSingle->save();
}
```